# Rigging separate objects

Tags: rigging, parent

I'm new to Blender. I tried rigging a character made up of separate objects. Parenting the forearm bone to the forearm works but moves it and changes its size. I tried applying the transformations of both the armature and the object, resetting their size to 1 etc, but the connection still ruins my placement. Is there any way to parent two objects whilst retaining their original transformations, and then move on from there? Thanks.

Comment: Hello please share your file